# get error when try to find idxmin or idxmax for a groupby object if there is missing datetime

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have stock tick data. I grouped these data to 1 minute. When try to find the idxmin or idxmax, I get an error. This error due that the groupby object contains groups with no data (weekends and holidays when the market is closed). Is there a way to solve that?

```
data : biddf_master
                         Bdp    Bdv
Time        
2019-01-01 22:02:37.254 1.14598 3.75
2019-01-01 22:02:38.590 1.14599 2.25
2019-01-01 22:02:39.138 1.14599 3.75
2019-01-01 22:02:55.787 1.14598 3.75
2019-01-01 22:03:02.060 1.14598 3.75
```

code:

```
troughs = biddf_master.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="D"))['Bdp'].idxmin(skipna=True)
```

error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-57ddac9a638f> in <module>
----> 1 troughs = biddf_master.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="D"))['Bdp'].idxmin(skipna=True)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    643 
    644             try:
--> 645                 return self.apply(curried)
    646             except TypeError as err:
    647                 if not re.search(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    222     )
    223     def apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
--> 224         return super().apply(func, *args, **kwargs)
    225 
    226     @Substitution(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    734         with option_context("mode.chained_assignment", None):
    735             try:
--> 736                 result = self._python_apply_general(f)
    737             except TypeError:
    738                 # gh-20949

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _python_apply_general(self, f)
    750 
    751     def _python_apply_general(self, f):
--> 752         keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, self._selected_obj, self.axis)
    753 
    754         return self._wrap_applied_output(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py in apply(self, f, data, axis)
    204             # group might be modified
    205             group_axes = group.axes
--> 206             res = f(group)
    207             if not _is_indexed_like(res, group_axes):
    208                 mutated = True

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in curried(x)
    631 
    632             def curried(x):
--> 633                 return f(x, *args, **kwargs)
    634 
    635             # preserve the name so we can detect it when calling plot methods,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in idxmin(self, axis, skipna, *args, **kwargs)
   2037         """
   2038         skipna = nv.validate_argmin_with_skipna(skipna, args, kwargs)
-> 2039         i = nanops.nanargmin(com.values_from_object(self), skipna=skipna)
   2040         if i == -1:
   2041             return np.nan

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py in _f(*args, **kwargs)
     67             try:
     68                 with np.errstate(invalid="ignore"):
---> 69                     return f(*args, **kwargs)
     70             except ValueError as e:
     71                 # we want to transform an object array

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py in nanargmin(values, axis, skipna, mask)
    904         values, True, fill_value_typ="+inf", mask=mask
    905     )
--> 906     result = values.argmin(axis)
    907     result = _maybe_arg_null_out(result, axis, mask, skipna)
    908     return result

ValueError: attempt to get argmin of an empty sequence
```

Comment: Works for me with pandas 1.2.4. What version are you using ? And can you post a code [example of the error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please give more details, and a minimal reproducible example with code you wrote yet / sample data / and full error messages
about your trial to solve this problem, so we can reproduce and help.
See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I just edited the questio include data sample, code, and error.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a little weird, but apparently pandas is able to take the idxmin from a sequence of `NaN`s:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': [1, 2, None, None, 3, 4], 'time': np.arange(6) // 2})
df.groupby('time')['data'].idxmin()
```

returns:

```
time
0    0.0
1    NaN
2    4.0
Name: data, dtype: float64
```

However it can not take an empty sequence apparently. Reproducing your example with a date missing in the sequence (I skipped a day by shifting some dates in the index) does trigger the error:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(sep=';', index_col='Time', parse_dates=['Time'],
                 filepath_or_buffer=io.StringIO('''Time;Bdp;Bdv
2019-01-01 22:02:37.254;1.14598;3.75
2019-01-01 22:02:38.590;1.14599;2.25
2019-01-03 22:02:39.138;1.14599;3.75
2019-01-03 22:02:55.787;1.14598;3.75
2019-01-03 22:03:02.060;1.14598;3.75'''))
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))['Bdp'].idxmin()
```

This throws:

```
ValueError: attempt to get argmin of an empty sequence
```

So we should try to avoid creating empty sequences. Because you can pass any sequence of the right length to `groupby()`, you can try to transform the index to the dates, for example with [pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html):

```py
df.groupby(df.index.floor(freq='D'))['Bdp'].idxmin()
```

This works:

```
Time
2019-01-01   2019-01-01 22:02:37.254
2019-01-03   2019-01-03 22:02:55.787
Name: Bdp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Note that the index now does not contain any of the missing dates. You can `reindex` with a `pd.date_range` if you want them back in.

```py
min_bdp_times = df.groupby(df.index.floor(freq='D'))['Bdp'].idxmin()
min_bdp_times.reindex(pd.date_range(min_bdp_times.index.min(), min_bdp_times.index.max(), freq='D'))
```

Which returns:

```
2019-01-01   2019-01-01 22:02:37.254
2019-01-02                       NaT
2019-01-03   2019-01-03 22:02:55.787
Freq: D, Name: Bdp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```